# Bazel Scala "failed: Worker process did not return a WorkResponse"

Tags: java, scala, jvm, bazel

I am a beginner in Bazel and I need to migrate from `sbt`. I use [Scala Rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/) to build my app.

I use the following dependencies with following aliases (to prevent typos):

| Alias | Group | Artifact | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `borer_core` | `io.bullet` | `borer-core_2.12` | `1.6.3` |
| `borer_derivation` | `io.bullet` | `borer-derivation_2.12` | `1.6.3` |
| `scala_logging` | `com.typesafe.scala-logging` | `scala-logging_2.12` | `3.9.2` |
| `logback` | `ch.qos.logback` | `logback-classic` | `1.2.3` |
| `tagging` | `com.softwaremill.common` | `tagging_2.12` | `2.2.1` |
| `ujson` | `com.lihaoyi` | `ujson_2.12` | `1.2.2` |

All these dependencies will be installed by [JVM External Rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external). It looks like so in `Workspace`:

```
dp_deps = [
    borer_core,
    borer_derivation,
    scala_logging,
    logback,
    tagging,
    ujson,
]

maven_install(
    name = "maven",
    artifacts = dp_deps,
    repositories = ["http://repo1.maven.org/maven/"],
    fetch_sources = True
)
```

Then I try to build a `jar` with [scala_library](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/master/docs/scala_library.md) in my `BUILD` file. It looks so:

```
scala_library(
    name = "some_lib",
    srcs = glob(["some_lib/src/main/**/*.scala"]),
    unused_dependency_checker_mode = 'warn',
    deps = [
        "@maven//:io_bullet_borer_core_2_12",
        "@maven//:io_bullet_borer_derivation_2_12",
        "@maven//:com_typesafe_scala_logging_scala_logging_2_12",
        "@maven//:ch_qos_logback_logback_classic",
        "@maven//:com_softwaremill_common_tagging_2_12",
        "@maven//:com_lihaoyi_ujson_2_12"
    ]
)
```

Then I try to build it with the following command:

```sh
bazel build //test-dir:some_lib --verbose_failures
```

and I receive the following Error with Log:
Error:

```
ERROR: /Users/<edited>/test-dir/BUILD.bazel:136:14: scala //test-dir:some_lib failed: Worker process did not return a WorkResponse:
```

Log:

```
---8<---8<--- Start of log snippet, file at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_<edited>/07059176926c1842b8d4e633b0ddf1f4/bazel-workers/worker-7-Scalac.log ---8<---8<---
[... truncated ...]
scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.expand(Macros.scala:622)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.apply(Macros.scala:609)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand(Macros.scala:784)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand$(Macros.scala:782)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$4.standardMacroExpand(Global.scala:480)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$10.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:457)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$10.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:454)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:411)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:454)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:454)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$4.pluginsMacroExpand(Global.scala:480)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand(Macros.scala:773)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand$(Macros.scala:766)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$4.macroExpand(Global.scala:480)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.vanillaAdapt$1(Typers.scala:1164)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1227)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1200)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1220)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5747)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedValDefImpl(Typers.scala:5949)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedValDef(Typers.scala:2056)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5651)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5733)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5797)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3357)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3357)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:2017)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedModuleDef(Typers.scala:1883)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5654)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5733)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5797)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3357)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3357)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5363)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5656)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5733)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.apply(Analyzer.scala:115)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:451)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.run(Analyzer.scala:104)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1501)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1485)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1478)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:47)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:32)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:67)
    at io.bazel.rulesscala.scalac.ScalacWorker.compileScalaSources(ScalacWorker.java:226)
    at io.bazel.rulesscala.scalac.ScalacWorker.work(ScalacWorker.java:70)
    at io.bazel.rulesscala.worker.Worker.persistentWorkerMain(Worker.java:92)
    at io.bazel.rulesscala.worker.Worker.workerMain(Worker.java:46)
    at io.bazel.rulesscala.scalac.ScalacWorker.main(ScalacWorker.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.bullet.borer.deriver.Deriver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 75 more
---8<---8<--- End of log snippet, 2207 chars omitted ---8<---8<---
Target //test-dir:some_lib failed to build
```

How can I resolve this error? The `io.bullet.borer.deriver.Deriver` is in dependencies and classpath but JVM doesn't see it. Cannot log classpath of the sandbox, because bazel cannot get `WorkerResponce`. Please help me .

Comment: I have created a [Github repository to easily reproduce the error](https://github.com/sierikov/b1256).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. Default `scala_toolchain` has `direct` mode. So it sees only dependencies, that are defined in the `deps` filed of `scala_library` or `scala_macro_library`. So there are two options to solve this problem:

1. Add all needed direct dependencies to the `deps` array.
2. Or define own `scala_toolchain` - [docs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/master/docs/scala_toolchain.md) - [example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/master/scala/BUILD#L36-L43)

So for the current example, we need to define all direct dependencies. By the way, they are already downloaded when you do `maven_install`. Now we need only reference them:

For `borer` additional dependencies will be:

- `@maven//:io_bullet_borer_deriver_2_12`

For `scala_logging` we need to add:

- `@maven//:org_slf4j_slf4j_api`

And for `ujson` we need:

- `@maven//:com_lihaoyi_geny_2_12`
- `@maven//:com_lihaoyi_upickle_core_2_12`

All fixes for the [Github example repository](https://github.com/sierikov/b1256) are available in the repository under `fix` branches.

- [Borer fix](https://github.com/sierikov/b1256/tree/fix/some-borer)
- [Spark fix](https://github.com/sierikov/b1256/tree/fix/some-spark)